# How can I avoid a single tag container to send data to different properties of a same account

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am a newbie regarding the proper usage of Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager.

Basically right now I have a page within a domain (ex: acme.com)

But I also have several other subdomains (ex: checkout.acme.com, blog.acme.com) and are different sites (of the same company).

The current setup in GA is that we have a single account with 2 properties: for "acme.com" and "blog.acme.com".

I created a single Google Tag Manager (TGM) container that is used in both these properties.

When creating a PageView tag inside the container, you need to specify the Tracking ID.

So I created two PageView tags inside the same container but with different Tracking IDs (one for the property "acme.com" and another for "blog.acme.com")

The problem is that when I go to GoogleAnalytics and I choose the property "blog.acme.com" and I go to any report, for example, RealTime reports, I see the traffic of "acme.com".

How can I avoid this? Or what is the proper way of doing things?

Comment: Despite not knowing exactly why this behaves the way it does, it may be easier to implement just having a different tag manager container for that specific subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a lookup table variable, where you match the hostname (you need to enable page hostname in the built-in variables tab) to a tracking id. Then use the lookup table in your GA tag or settings variable.

If you want the accounts to be truly independent you might have to change other settings too (e.g. the cookie name for GA, else both properties will use the same cookie).

Comment: Yes. I think your proposed solution to use a lookup table variable is not a bad idea but not necessary (at least for me).
What I did to make it work is just to define better the conditions that trigger the tags according its hostname.

Comment: The lookup table solution has the advantage that you don't need to duplicate your tags - just fire on the "All pages" trigger, and the proper Account will be set by the lookup table.

Comment: You are right, it's a nice solution! These provides for a cleaner way of doing things.